# does $ \sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\left(\cos^n\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)-\frac{1}{\sqrt{e}}\right) $ converge?

Tags: convergence-divergence

I'm trying to find out whether $\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\left(\cos^n\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)-\frac{1}{\sqrt{e}}\right)$ converges or not. I've tried with taylor series but it doesn't lead me anywhere except with the fact that $\lim_{n \to \infty}\cos^n\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)-\frac{1}{\sqrt{e}}=0$ and therefore it has "a chance" to converge.

Any hint?

Comment: Hint: 

$$
\cos^n\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt n}\right) = \mathrm e ^{n \ln\cos\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt n}\right) } =  \mathrm e ^{n \ln\left(1+\cos\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt n}\right) -1\right)}
$$

Comment: $\cos^n x = (\cos x)^n$, not the composition of $n$ cosines?

Comment: @GEdgar yes it's $(\cos x)^n$

Comment: @SewerKeeper I did something similar, done the taylor series expansion but i end up stuck with $\exp(-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4n} + o(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}))$ and the thing inside $\exp$ doesn't tends to $0$ so I can't continue with taylor series?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**hint**

$$\cos(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})=1-\frac{1}{2n}+\frac{1}{24n^2}+o(\frac{1}{n^2})$$

$$\ln(1+\cos(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})-1)=$$

$$-\frac{1}{2n}-\frac{1}{12n^2}+o(1/n^2)$$

thus

$$\cos^n(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})=e^{n\ln(\cos(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}))}$$

$$=e^{-\frac 12}e^{-\frac 1n(\frac{1}{12}+o(1))}$$
$$=\frac{1}{\sqrt{e}}(1-\frac{1}{12n}(1+o(1))$$

Answer (score 0):

The $n$-th term is asymptotic to $$-\frac{1}{12 \sqrt{e} n}$$ so, alas, the series diverges.

Answer (score 0):

Note that
$$
\cos\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sim1-\frac{1}{2n}+\frac{1}{24n^2}+\ldots,
$$
so
$$
\log\cos\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}= \log\left(1-\left(\frac{1}{2n}-\frac{1}{24n^2}+\ldots\right)\right)\\=-\left(\frac{1}{2n}-\frac{1}{24n^2}+\ldots\right)-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{2n}+\ldots\right)^2+\ldots\\=-\frac{1}{2n}-\frac{1}{12n^2}+\ldots.
$$
So
$$
\cos^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}=\exp\left(n\log \cos\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right) \\ = \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{12n}+\ldots\right) \\ =\frac{1}{\sqrt{e}}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{12n}+\ldots\right)\\ =\frac{1}{\sqrt{e}}-\frac{1}{12n\sqrt{e}}+O(n^{-2}).
$$
Hence the terms are asymptotic to $-\frac{1}{12n\sqrt{e}}$, and the sum diverges.